# Enable selection only on checkbox in Fluent UI DetailsList component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I use DetailsList component in Fluent UI. I can select multiple items. The problem is that I have to make this selection only on the checkbox, not outside of the checkbox.
With the current implementation, I can select row item wherever I click on the row. I need to disable this and make the selection only on the checkbox.

DetailsList component:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist

I tried some props but they didn't work as I wanted, here are some props I tried:

- disableAutoSelectOnInputElements: true,
- disableSelectionZone={true}
- isSelectedOnFocus={true}
- selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={false}

Also this one:
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/11934